# Run same Cypress tests multiple times (for different domains)

Tags: cypress, integration-testing

I need to test the same logic hosted on different domains e.g.

```js
cy.visit('DomainA');
cy.sameTestLogic();

cy.visit('DomainB'); 
cy.sameTestLogic();
```

There are entire suites of tests that need to run on both domains, A and B. Does anyone have any suggestions based on experience on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the domains like this (applied per spec)

```js
const domains = ['a', 'b']

domains.forEach(domain => {

  describe(`Testing domain ${domain}`, () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit(domain)
    })

    it('...', () =>
```

To do something more flexible, take a look at the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#cypress-run)

**Node script**

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')

const domains = ['a', 'b']

domains.forEach(domain => {

  // run all specs or as specified
  cypress.run({
    ...
    env: {
      domain
    },
  })
})
```

**Test**

```js
const domain = Cypress.env('domain')
cy.visit(domain)
```